# Crystal Report issues with multiple SQL tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I have to make a report that sums the value of two different tables, and I'm using CR on VB, what I have is two fields named `value` from two different tables, the table `Products` and the Table `Services`, I need to sum those values and show them on a report. I already used the select and tried writing down a formula with the "formula" function on CR but I just can't figure it out how to do it. That's my insert

```
SELECT product, value FROM TbProduct
UNION
SELECT Description as product, value from TbService
```

thanks in advance

Comment: that's my select* sorry, what I need is basically a way to sum two fields from different tables and show them on CR

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure on the SQL side and set up the CR using that stored procedure as a data source.  (I don't remember quite how to do that but I know I've done it in the past.)  This can offer a way of optimizing queries for use with CR and not depending on CR's SQL generator.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "stored procedure" bro, sorry, total newb here